# How to insert window.load function to existing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the page to wait until all images are loaded and ready before displaying them. Where in the code below will I insert `$(window).load(function(){ }`?

**Code**

```
function adshandler() {
var d = new Date();
var cache = d.getTime();
$.getJSON("check_time.php?cache=" + cache, function(update) {
    if (update.count === true) {
        location.reload();
    }
}); 
} 
setInterval(adshandler, 600000);
```

Comment: With amount of delay you are using it wouldn't make any difference

Comment: The delay only check every 10 minutes if there is any new content in the database to display.

Comment: right...so why would you need to wait for all images to load to start a timer that won't do anything for 10 minutes?

Comment: You can use [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin.

Comment: I want to start displaying the images once all images has loaded, to prevent a buffer effect. The question has nothing to do to start the timer.

Comment: Well that's the only code you have shown...so how would we know any different? There is nothing shown in question that relates to the DOM at all

Comment: @charlietfl. The question : "I need the page to wait until all images are loaded and ready before displaying them" can surely not be that confusing?

Comment: Why the down vote? Because of your lack of understanding a basic question?

Comment: Because of the irrelevant code in the question. Can put the load handler anywhere as it has nothing to do with code shown. You asked ... *"Where in the code below will I insert..."*

Comment: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/